# How can I test Eddystone beacons using the Proximity Beacon API on Android or iOS and are there any dependencies?

Tags: google-beacon-platform, eddystone

I saw the announcement Google made regarding Eddystone and want to start testing on my smartphone devices. Can you please provide some links where I can get started and do I need to download any particular dependencies? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tutorial I wrote on how to build a basic Eddystone-capable app:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/14/building-apps-with-eddystone.html

This app will run on any Android phone with version 4.3+.  The only dependency you need is the free and open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/).  The library documentation includes lots of details on how to use [all of the different Eddystone frames](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-support.html), and [how to program detection of each one](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-how-to.html).

A few other things you might find useful:

- Developer Kits with hardware Eddystone beacons can be purchased from Radius Networks (my company) [here](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/eddystone-devkit).
- You can use the free Android [Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate) to detect and decode all of the frames transmitted by Eddystone.
- You can use the same Locate app above to act as a **FREE** Eddystone transmitter

Comment: If I have my android app as receiver integrated using estimote sdk then can i test it against the locate app transmitting eddystone-url frame ? OR i will compulsorily require estimote hardware beacon ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Nexus 6 or Nexus 9 you can transmit as an Eddystone beacon using txeddystone-uid application:

https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid/tools/txeddystone-uid

Also, you can use ios-eddystone-scanner-sample application to scan Eddystone beacons.

https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/tools/ios-eddystone-scanner-sample

If you have Estimote beacons you can upgrade their firmware to transmit as an Eddystone beacon.

http://developer.estimote.com/eddystone/#configure-estimote-beacons-to-broadcast-eddystone

Comment: Can phone transmit Eddystone-URL frame type?

Comment: @AB1209 yes, for that you can use https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid/tools/txeddystone-uid

Answer (score 0):

You can download sample apps for Android and iOS at our GitHub repo:  https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/tree/master/samples

For Android, enumerated in the app's build.gradle, we require:

- Android 5.1
- Google Play Services (for account management and authorization utilities)
- Volley (Async HTTP library)
- Joda-Time

Answer (score 0):

You can test Eddystone even without your app in IOS. It works with IOS Chrome widget released with latest Chrome update 44.0.2403.+

You just need to install Eddystone profile on any beacon (I have tested with estimote beacons) and configure any URL.

Here you can find how to setup Eddystone beacon using estimote beacons.
http://developer.estimote.com/eddystone/

Once you have it, Just add the Chrome widget in your notification. First it will ask for permission and after that each time you go to notifications center it  scans for Eddystone beacons.

You can also do Scanning for your app using estimote sdk but it doesn't provide background scanning.